# Programa soma de fração (Sobrecarga de Classe)

Tags: c, c++

Boa noite, tenho uma dúvida no meu programa de soma de duas frações utilizando sobrecarga de classes, na qual o programa ele está sempre imprimindo o mesmo valor, mesmo modificando os parâmetros das duas funções, obrigado!!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Fracao {
  private:
  double numerador;
  double denominador;

 public :
  inline Fracao(double = 0, double = 0);
  int getNum();
  int getDenom();
  double getValor();
  void setnumer(int newnum);
  void setdenom(int newden);
  friend Fracao operator + (Fracao &, Fracao&);
  inline void mostra();
};


int main () {

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
  Fracao F3;
  Fracao F1 (4,3); // Numero 4/3
  Fracao F2 (8,10); // Numero 8/10
  F1.mostra(); F2.mostra(); 
  cout << "\n\nSoma de F1 + F2 = ";
  F3 = F1 + F2;
  cout << F3.getValor() << endl;
  return 0;
}


//Construtor
Fracao :: Fracao(double n, double d) {
  numerador = n;
  denominador = d;
}

//Modificadores
int Fracao::getNum(){
return numerador;
}

int Fracao::getDenom(){
  return denominador;
}

double Fracao::getValor(){
  return numerador / denominador;
}


void Fracao::setnumer(int novoNum){
numerador = novoNum;
}

void Fracao::setdenom(int newDen){
  denominador = newDen;
}

//Sobrecarga
Fracao operator + (Fracao &prim, Fracao &segun){
double novoDenom = prim.getDenom() * segun.getDenom();
double novoNum = prim.getNum() * segun.getDenom() + prim.getNum() * segun.getDenom();
Fracao *F3 = new Fracao(novoNum,novoDenom);
return *F3;
}


void Fracao :: mostra() {
  cout << "\nNumero Fracionário = " << this->numerador
       << " / " << this->denominador;
}
```

Comment: vc pode usar std::ratio https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio

Answer (score 1):

> Boa noite, tenho uma dúvida no meu programa de soma de duas frações utilizando sobrecarga de classes, na qual o programa ele está sempre imprimindo o mesmo valor, mesmo modificando os parâmetros das duas funções, obrigado

- Não se trata de sobrecarga de classes, há apenas uma classe no programa
- imagino que se referia à redefinição --- overload/sobrecarga --- do operador `+` para somar instâncias de `Fracao`.
- C e C++ são diferentes animais. Não deveria usar as duas *tags*

#### Sobre seu programa

- O código está bem confuso: devia resolver se vai usar `int` ou `double` porque misturar os dois pode destruir seu resultado por conversões inesperadas e truncamento.
- Use nomes mais expressivos e coerentes: Usou `getNum()` mas `setnumber()` por exemplo. Defina algo e use só aquilo. Ou usa a maiúscula no meio ou hífen e abrevia `numerador` e `denominador` sempre da mesma maneira
- A soma retorna uma nova variável, mas não use `new`
- se usa um overload para `+` e tem uma função `mostra()` grande chance de que ficaria mais simples usar também um overload para `<<` certo?
- getters em geral são marcados `const`.
- se usa getters não precisa de `friend` para somar. Se usa friend talvez possa prescindir dos getters

#### Um exemplo com seu código

Note a maneira mais simples de declarar o construtor e o fato de que a soma de `Fracao` não faz parte da classe.

```
class Fracao
{
private:
    double numerador;
    double denominador;

public :
    inline  Fracao(double n = 0, double d = 0) :
        numerador(n), denominador(d){};

    double  getNumer() const;
    double  getDenom() const;
    double  getValor() const;

    void    setNumer(double newNumer);
    void    setDenom(double newDenom);

public:
    friend ostream&     operator<<( ostream& o, const Fracao&);

};  // class Fracao()
```

#### saída de seu programa

```
F1 = [ 4 / 3 ]
F2 = [ 8 / 10 ]
F3 = [ 0 / 0 ]


Soma de F1 + F2 = [ 64 / 30 ]
F3 = F1 + F2 = [ 64 / 30 ]

Valor de F3: 2.13333
```

#### Seu programa alterado para usar essa classe:

```
int main(void)
 {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
  Fracao F3;
  Fracao F1 (4,3); // Numero 4/3
  Fracao F2 (8,10); // Numero 8/10
  cout << "F1 = " << F1;
  cout << "F2 = " << F2;
  cout << "F3 = " << F3;
  cout << "\n\nSoma de F1 + F2 = " << (F1+F2);
  F3 = F1 + F2;
  cout << "F3 = F1 + F2 = " << F3 << "\n";
  cout << "Valor de F3: " << F3.getValor() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Veja que fica mais simples de ler com o overload de `<<`

#### O programa todo

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Fracao
{
private:
    double numerador;
    double denominador;

public :
    inline  Fracao(double n = 0, double d = 0) :
        numerador(n), denominador(d){};

    double  getNumer() const;
    double  getDenom() const;
    double  getValor() const;

    void    setNumer(double newNumer);
    void    setDenom(double newDenom);

public:
    friend ostream&     operator<<( ostream& o, const Fracao&);

};  // class Fracao()

Fracao      operator+(const Fracao& um, const Fracao& outro);

int main(void)
 {
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
  Fracao F3;
  Fracao F1 (4,3); // Numero 4/3
  Fracao F2 (8,10); // Numero 8/10
  cout << "F1 = " << F1;
  cout << "F2 = " << F2;
  cout << "F3 = " << F3;
  cout << "\n\nSoma de F1 + F2 = " << (F1+F2);
  F3 = F1 + F2;
  cout << "F3 = F1 + F2 = " << F3 << "\n";
  cout << "Valor de F3: " << F3.getValor() << endl;
  return 0;
}

Fracao  operator+( const Fracao& um, const Fracao& outro)
{
    double Num =  um.getNumer() * outro.getDenom();
    Num += outro.getNumer() * um.getDenom();
    double Den =  um.getDenom() * outro.getDenom();
    return Fracao(Num,Den);
};

ostream&  operator<< ( ostream& o, const Fracao& f)
    {
        o << "[ " <<  
            f.numerador << " / " <<
            f.denominador << " ]\n";
        return o;
    };

//Modificadores
double      Fracao::getNumer() const
{ return numerador; };

double      Fracao::getDenom() const
{ return denominador; };
 
double      Fracao::getValor() const
{ return double (numerador / denominador); };

void        Fracao::setNumer(double novoNum)
{ numerador = novoNum; };

void        Fracao::setDenom(double newDenom)
{ denominador = newDenom; };
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi fazer a classe Frac em termos de C++ "moderno"

1 - Sem setter e getter para tipos "valor"

2 - Template para tipos algebricos

3 - UDL para criar os valores constantes (no lugar do construtor)

4 - Sobrecarga de operadores para utilização "natural"

https://godbolt.org/z/ezK55a

Att